# invalid operands of types double* and double to binary operator&

Tags: c

New to programming and writing C code for class.  My program is suppose to take data from a .txt file, compute, then print results to a .txt file.

I'm getting:

> invalid operands of types double* and double to binary operator&

at line `fscanf(therm, "%lf %lf",&temp &con);` (`for` loop near the bottom)

```
/* Preprocessor directives */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define inputfile "c:\\engr 200\\thermal.txt"
#define outputfile "c:\\engr 200\\results.txt"

/*Main function*/
int main (void)
{

    /*Declare and intialize variables*/
    double temp, sumtemp = 0.0, con, sumcon = 0.0, tem_con, sumtem_con =
        0.0, tsq, sumtsq = 0.0;
    int i, ndata;
    FILE *therm, *res;

    /*Open files*/
    therm = fopen (inputfile, "r");
    res = fopen (outputfile, "w");

    /*Print output headings*/
    printf ("******************************************");
    printf ("\nTEMPERATURE vs THERMAL CONDUCTIVITY");
    printf ("\nby ");
    printf ("\n\nTemp    Conduct    Temp Sqrd    Temp*Conduct");

    /* Verify input file and read control number */
    // NOTE: unmatched 'else' followed, presuming a
    //       test for 'therm'
    if (!therm)
    {
        printf ("\n\n\n\n   ERROR OPENING INPUT FILE.");
        printf ("\n\n   PROGRAM TERMINATED.\n\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Read control number */
        fscanf (therm, "%i", &ndata);

        /* Compute temp and conductivity data and print results */
        for (i = 1; i <= ndata; i++) {
            fscanf (therm, "%lf %lf", &temp & con);
            sumtemp = sumtemp + temp;
            sumcon = sumcon + con;
            sumtsq = sumtsq + pow (temp, 2);
            sumtem_con = sumtem_con + temp * con;
            printf ("\n%3.0f   %5.1f   %6.1f  %6.1f", sumtemp, sumcon, sumtsq,
                    sumtem_con);
            fprintf (res, "%3.0f   %5.1f   %6.1f  %6.1f", sumtemp, sumcon,
                    sumtsq, sumtem_con);
        }
    }

    /*Close the input file*/
    fclose (therm);
    fclose (res);

    /*Exit the program*/
    return 0;
}
```

Could you help me diagnose this error?

Comment: shouldn't there be an if statement after the comment about verify input that matches up with the else?

Comment: triz - Most C compilers providing excellent *warning* and *error* information. Always, *always* compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra` to enable warnings and then *fix* all warnings before you attempt to run your code.

Answer (score 4):

You have missed the comma between the two variables, and if statement is also missing.

```
fscanf(therm, "%lf %lf", &temp &con);
```

This should be

```
fscanf(therm, "%lf %lf", &temp, &con);
```

There should be an if statement.

```
/* Verify input file and read control number */
```

Comment: i had the if statement in my program, just got missed when copying here.  Problem was the missing comma at between &temp and &con.  Thanks for all the help!